# Db to ListView error

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to create a list view from the database. this is the code

List Activity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.inbox);

  DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(InboxActivity.this);
  db.open();
  long userID = Long.parseLong(MessagingApplication.getUserID());

  Cursor inbox = db.readInbox(userID);
  startManagingCursor(inbox);

  String[] mails = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_NAME };

  int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name };

  SimpleCursorAdapter inboxmail = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
    R.layout.inbox_list, inbox, mails, to);

  setListAdapter(inboxmail);

  db.close();
 }
```

This is the code that fetches data from the DB

```
 public Cursor readInbox(long toId) throws SQLException {
  return db.query(TABLE_MAILS, new String[] { ID, KEY_FROM, KEY_TO,
    KEY_SUB, KEY_BODY, KEY_DATETIME, KEY_READ }, KEY_TO + "="
    + toId, null, null, null, null, null);
 }
```

My DB

```
private static final String CREATE_MAILS = "CREATE TABLE mails (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, pid INTEGER DEFAULT '0', from_id INTEGER, to_id INTEGER, subject TEXT, body TEXT, datetime TEXT, read INTEGER);";
```

Error:

[image]

http://variable3.com/files/screenshots/2010-12-29_1136.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column "_id" does not exist. Notice the underline in front of id. Please have a look at your log, it's written there.

Comment: my ID column is ID not _ID no where in the code i have used _id. dont understand where its fetching from ?

Comment: It's required. The adapter does need it. Just do "select id as _id ..." or rename the column.

Comment: am sure there must be a way to override it